# make custom attribute set as default selected

Tags: backend, magento-2.2.5, attribute-set

I have created new Attribute set say "My attribute set" . now when i add new product "default" one is selected by default , i want my custom attribute set to be selected as default one . i can not see any option in admin for same.

Also there in no option in Admin to set attribute set as default.
ALso there is no option to delete default one attribute set

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to set selected Attribute Set, set custom created Attribute Set as default one.

**Step 1) Find id of "Attribute Set" in database column eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id**

**Step 2) Run database query:**

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `default_attribute_set_id` = '%YOUR_Attribute_Set_ID%' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product';
```

**Step 3) Run Below commands:**

- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help!

Let me know if any issue.